# Insert row if not exists otherwise update sqlite - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

I know there have been a lot of questions on this in the past, but I seem to be unable to utilise those answers.  I have tried, but they don't seem to work.

I have a table which stores two user inputted values: name and email.  When they enter their name and e-mail, it gets stored into a single row of my table.

I want to be able to update this same row with a different name and email if the user types some other values, or insert these values if there weren't any previous values.

My code is here:

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
 transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Details(name,email)\
 VALUES(?,?)',[$('#entername').val(), $('#enteremail').val()],
 nullHandler,errorHandler);

 });
```

and the table creation is here if needed:

```
db.transaction(function(tx){
   tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Details(Id INTEGER NOT\
                   NULL PRIMARY KEY,name,email)',
                   [],nullHandler,errorHandler);
                           },errorHandler,successCallBack);
```

I have tried using INSERT OR REPLACE, but this just creates a new row with new details and leaves the previous row there with the old details.  Are there any efficient options relevant to my case?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work.  I had to do this:

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
 transaction.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Details(id,name,email)\
 VALUES(1,?,?)',[$('#entername').val(), $('#enteremail').val()],
 nullHandler,errorHandler);

 });
```

where id is the row id.  This replaces the first row with whatever else you type for name and email if it doesn't already exist